# Word for preventing unnecessary action: “you don't need to bother…”

Tags: word-choice

If I say to someone "do not X", I have (say) “prevented” them from doing X.  If I say “you don't need to bother doing X”, how do I express saving them from the unnecessary work of doing X?  Is there a better word than "prevent"?

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Please elaborate and also format the question for better understanding.

Comment: Someone had answered "exempted" — I thought that was really good.

Comment: Try *exempt* -- I don't know why the answer was deleted by the owner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *relieve, alleviate, lighten, assuage, mitigate, allay*

*... mean to make something less grievous. relieve implies a lifting of enough of a burden to make it tolerable . alleviate implies temporary or partial lessening of pain or distress . lighten implies reducing a burdensome or depressing weight . assuage implies softening or sweetening what is harsh or disagreeable . mitigate suggests a moderating or countering of the effect of something violent or painful . allay implies an effective calming or soothing of fears or alarms .*

([taken from the "relieve" definition page at merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relieve))

The first word that came to mind when reading this question was "relieve", and I immediately searched (using the Google engine) for "relieve definition", and expanded the definition it provided to find this third definition, second section:

> *free someone from (a tiresome responsibility).*
>   *"she relieved me of the household chores"*

Of these alternative words with similar meanings, I still think "relieve" is the most appropriate in this case, because it is more like "free" and "lighten", I mean it is closest to the meaning of "lessening" the burden / duties of someone/people. But refrain from using the specific phrase "relieved them of / from (their) duty / duties" because that means firing employees.

*Disclaimer*: I'm merely providing my findings and sharing my knowledge and opinion, but I'm no expert on the English language, in fact quite the opposite - my vocabulary is very poor, or should be since I can use my fingers to count how many fiction / novels I've read in both my native tongue and English, and I'm too young to say otherwise anyway. Also, I don't use English often other than watching TV and reading programming manuals...

**EDIT**: `In light of the recent discovery of a previous answer proposing "exempt" (mentioned by Neil G and Kris, in the comments section), I believe it is the most appropriate choice as well. I didn't get to see that had been answered previously because it had been deleted before I answered, so I have no idea who gave that answer.`

Answer (score 3):

You have *spared* them unnecessary effort.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spare

Verb, definition 3: to relieve of the necessity of doing or undergoing something.

Comment: Please elaborate..

Comment: Elaborated with a dictionary link.

Answer (score 1):

For the second one?

`saving them from the unnecessary work of doing X?`

`Discourage` or maybe `dissuade`?

Comment: +1 for "saving". You can save someone from having to do something.

Answer (score 1):

**[unburden](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unburden)** might fit. (it is used as disburden also)

> to take a problem or burden away from (someone or something)

Answer (score 1):

`saved` would be the correct word.

```
I have saved them from doing 'X'.
```